# How can I build a managed C++/CLI DLL library using CMake?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, managed-c++

I need to build a C++/CLI DLL as part of a larger CMake build. I found no preferred way to do this when I checked the documentation.

I tried to set up the CMake file for building a regular shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

project(ExampleProject LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(Example SHARED)
add_subdirectory(src)  # All source files are added here...

target_compile_features(Example PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_compile_definitions(Example PRIVATE
    UNICODE _UNICODE WIN32 DEBUG)
target_compile_options(Example PRIVATE
    /CLR /MP /W3 /Zi /Od /MDd /Zc:__cplusplus)
target_link_options(Example PRIVATE
    /DEBUG /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE)
```

Yet, CMake adds the option `/RTC1` incompatible with `/CLR`. So I wonder if there is managed C++ support for visual studio already built in CMake.

**How do I build a managed C++/CLI DLL library using CMake?**

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's precisely what I was searching for. I must have searched for the wrong terms. And yes, I am aware of the vague question and its negative impact. Yet, I think sometimes it is not possible to write a crisp and clear question with only a single answer. I will edit it so you can write a clear answer.

Comment: "Yet, I think sometimes it is not possible to write a crisp and clear question with only a single answer." - Single answered questions is not a purpose of Stack Overflow. In opposite, it is perfectly OK for a well-defined question to have multiple answers, so a future reader may select an answer which fits better to their task. Moreover, in my experience on Stack Overflow, I hardly remember a question which has only a single solution. (And even a single solution doesn't prevent an additional answer which provides much more detailed *explanations*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake provides [COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME.html) target property for adjust "managed" aspects of C++ code.

E.g. for make the target to contain a mixed (unmanaged/managed) code, set this property to the empty string:

```cmake
set_target_properties(Example PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME "")
```

---

Note, that property COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME is supported only for Visual Studio [generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators). E.g. for Ninja generator configured with `cl` compiler the property will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) works fine with Visual Studio generators (as he explained), making a build work with regular C++ code and C++/CLI code universally (e.g. ninja build) requires more steps.

See the following minimal example `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

project(ExampleProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "")

add_library(Example SHARED)
add_subdirectory(src) # All sources are added here

foreach(_lib_name mscorlib.dll System.dll System.Core.dll System.Data.dll System.DirectoryServices.dll System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll)
    list(APPEND _cli_compile_libs "/FU${_lib_name}")
endforeach()
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release|RelWithDebInfo")
    target_compile_definitions(Example PRIVATE
            UNICODE _UNICODE WIN32 _WINDOWS NDEBUG)
    target_compile_options(Example PRIVATE
            /MP /W3 /Zi /O2 /MD /GL /Zc:__cplusplus /CLR ${_cli_compile_libs})
    target_link_options(Example PRIVATE
            /DEBUG /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE /OPT:ICF /CLR)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(Example PRIVATE
            UNICODE _UNICODE WIN32 _WINDOWS DEBUG)
    target_compile_options(Example PRIVATE
            /MP /W3 /Zi /Od /MDd /Zc:__cplusplus /CLR ${_cli_compile_libs})
    target_link_options(Example PRIVATE
            /DEBUG /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE /CLR)
endif()
```

In the first step, the CMake variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS...` are emptied. This has to be done *before* the `add_library` statement to prevent the contents from being copied into the target.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "")
```

The problem, why this is necessary, are the flags `/RTC1` and `/EHsc` in these variables cause a conflict when sources are built with `/CLR`. By clearing these variables, you can manually control all flags for the individual targets with the `target_...` statements.

In this example I only cover the `Debug`, `Release` and `ReleaseWithDebInfo` build profiles. If you use more or different ones, you must also clear the corresponding variables.

```
foreach(_lib_name mscorlib.dll System.dll System.Core.dll System.Data.dll System.DirectoryServices.dll System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll)
    list(APPEND _cli_compile_libs "/FU${_lib_name}")
endforeach()
```

The next section prepares `/FU` options that include required .NET libraries for your build.

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release|RelWithDebInfo")
```

The `if` statement applies different flags for debug and release builds.

```
    target_compile_definitions(Example PRIVATE
            UNICODE _UNICODE WIN32 _WINDOWS NDEBUG)
    target_compile_options(Example PRIVATE
            /MP /W3 /Zi /O2 /MD /GL /Zc:__cplusplus /CLR ${_cli_compile_libs})
    target_link_options(Example PRIVATE
            /DEBUG /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE /OPT:ICF /CLR)
```

I use `target_compile_definitions`, `target_compile_options` and `target_link_options` to apply the flags only for one target. Most of the definitions and flags in my example are required defaults for the Visual Studio 2017 compiler to build C++/CLI DLL.

The flags in the example build a release library but create a debug database for the release and the debug builds.

### Further Notes

- When the flags in the `CMAKE_CXX_...` variables are cleared, they affect *all following* `add_library` and `add_executable` targets. Therefore, if you like to affect only this single library, backup the contents of all these variables and restore them at the end of your CMake file.
- I extracted this example from our local build system. If you work with large projects with many targets like this, write a small CMake library that allows you to apply all these settings with a single function call. It will make maintenance and upgrading much easier.

```
function(my_compiler_setup)
    set(options APPLICATION LIBRARY SHARED CLI)
    set(oneValueArgs TARGET)
    set(multiValueArgs "")
    cmake_parse_arguments(CXX_SETUP "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})

    # Configure the target here...
endfunction()
```

After writing this function, you can import it and set up the target like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

project(ExampleProject LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(Example SHARED)
add_subdirectory(src)
my_compiler_setup(TARGET Example LIBRARY SHARED CLI)
```

The statements that clear the variables with the flags are placed in the main CMake project file to ensure they do not affect any target in your build.